# loaded php.ini file doesn't 'work'

Tags: windows-vista, php

The php.ini file that is loaded (checked through phpinfo) does not seem to have any effect when I change something (after restarting apache). I'm using vista for this (please no answers about use linux, I use that too, I want to have it work on vista also).

edit: version 5.3 VC6 x86 Thread Safe, apache 2.2
edit2: version 5.2.10 VC6 x86 Thread Safe works normal

Comment: In the output of phpinfo(), there is an entry indicating "Loaded Configuration File".
Is this really this file you are editing ?

Comment: Yes it's the loaded configuration file.

Comment: First step OK, then ^^
Have you checked in Apache's error_log file ?
And, just out of curiosity, what happens if you try to call PHP via the command line ? ("php -m", for instance, to list the loaded extensions)

Comment: The error log reports nothing special and php -m works as expected.

Comment: well, I have to admit, I don't really have ideas here ^^ I've just installed PHP 5.3 on my laptop, which has a vista partition, and have no problem modifying php.ini and getting modifications take into account... Did you modify much of the php.ini file ? What kind of modifications are you trying to make ?

Comment: Does the PHPINFO() page show your changes in the output? If not, I suspect you are changing the wrong file. Try temporarily deleting the php.ini file and restart apache. If it works, then bingo - wrong file.

Comment: Does this affect all modifications of PHP.ini? What changes did you make, specifically? Bad syntax can cause changes to be ignored, reverting back to compiled-in defaults.

Answer (score 1):

call phpinfo() function or in CLI php -i
and check "Loaded Configuration File" to see exact php.ini file loaded

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the php.ini file is placed in the correct place? Are you using IIS with PHP or just apache?

You could try to reinstall the webserver.

Comment: It's apache. I can try to reinstall, can't hurt.

Comment: I just got remembered something. When you modify the php.ini it SAVES the file modifications? Because it's in Windows folder and usually you don't have rights on it, only if you use the Open With Admin rights. Try that one;)

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple php.ini. In the case of XAMPP, there is one at "U:\xampp\php\" and one in "U:\xampp\apache\bin". The former is for PHP CLI.

Comment: I'm not using XAMPP but the VC6 x86 Thread Safe zip version. I haven't enabled the included suggested ini configurations either.

Comment: There is now only one php.ini file for php and apache to share. There is however a php-pear.ini, so presumably pear has it's own (not that it is very different than the normal one...).